# strtol giving same answer for two different hex strings

Tags: c++, decimal, hex, strtol

So I have two hex strings - `"3b101c091d53320c000910"` and  `"071d154502010a04000419"`. When I use `strtol()` on them I get same value for both strings.

I tried the following code-

```
    string t1="3b101c091d53320c000910";
    long int hext1=strtol(t1.c_str(),0,16);
    string t2="071d154502010a04000419";
    long int hext2=strtol(t2.c_str(),0,16);
    cout<<hext1<<endl;
    cout<<hext2<<endl;
```

Both are giving me same value: `9223372036854775807`.

I dont know how strtol() works exactly since I am new to C++ but it's giving me same value for two different hex strings. Why?

Comment: The value of these strings is too large to fit within a long int. The value you are getting as a result: 9223372036854775807, is the largest positive value that can fit within a variable of type long int.

Answer (score 5):

You should start by [reading the manual page](http://linux.die.net/man/3/strtol). It's returning `LONG_MAX` since you're input is too large to fit in a `long`.

Also, `strtol()` is a very C way of doing things, and you're programming in C++.

Comment: On the other hand, creating an `std::istringstream`, and checking that everything has been consumed, is a pretty heavy solution. I agree that it is probably the one which should be taught first, or at least the one which should be used by a beginner, but `std::strtol` is perfectly valid C++.

Answer (score 0):

You're not using `strtol` correctly.  You should set `errno` to
0 before calling it, and check that it is still 0 after;
otherwise, it will contain an error code (which can be displayed
using `strerror`).  Also, you should pass it the address of
a `char const*`, so that you can ensure that it has processed
the entire string (otherwise, `"abc"` will return 0, without an
error):

```
errno = 0;
char const* end;
long hext1 = strtol( t1.c_str(), &end, 16 );
if ( errno != 0 || *end != '\0' ) {
    //  Error occured.
}
```